# Cause of slicing artifacts layers not connecting diagonal errors

Tags: print-quality, 3d-design, slicing

Sometimes my meshes turn out with artifacts Which can be seen in the bottom image. What is the cause? The first image shows my mesh which its generated from.
I've tried multiple slicers. This tends to occur sometimes.
Any help appreciated. Is there something going over my head???

[image: mesh wireframe]

[image: Artifacts in 3d model]

Answer (score 1):

The artifacts you spot in your slices do not come from the slicer, they are actually present in the STL file you export.

I suggest checking your model for problems like vertices that share a position or edges that are parallel but not joined. Use the `remove doubles` function in blender to merge up these vertices. Then make sure that your surface consists of only squares and triangles to aid the stl generation.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was solved by disabling coasting in the options within the slicer